# http get request with strange chars \t in url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Hi everyone I have trying to make a rest API request (the rest API is written in node js and my frontend is in angularjs) based on a group of permissions name instead of his id. I just have the name of the group and I need to make a API request to get the id to perform update options based on id.

I'm making a get request like

```
/api/organization_permissions_groups/getPermissionGroupId/?permissionGroup=Monitor%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09
```

And I'm getting error 500 cause of this `%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09`.

Is there a way to remove? In nodej this part is seen as `Monitor\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t`.

orgnizationsController (angular js - client side)

```
 $scope.navigateToViews = function() {
    var btn = event.currentTarget;          
        groupName = btn.parentNode.parentElement.innerText;

    if(groupName!=null){
        console.log("groupName ",groupName);
        $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups/getPermissionGroupId/',
                   {params: {permissionGroup: groupName}})
          .success(function (data) {
            if(data!=undefined && data != null){
                $rootScope.groupId=data;
                console.log("controllerScope.id ",$rootScope.groupId);
            }
        });
    }

    console.log("controllerScope.id views ",$rootScope.groupId);
    $state.go('app.organizationViews');

}
```

In my restApi for OrganizationPermissionsGroupsController.js I have

```
OrganizationPermissionsGroupsController.prototype.setRoutes = function (express) {
    var router = express.Router();

router.route('/getPermissionGroupId/')
        .get(passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: true}) this.getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName);
}

    OrganizationPermissionsGroupsController.prototype.getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName = function (req, res, next) {


createLog('info', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName', 'inicio');

var data = req.query.permissionGroup.toString();
createLog('debug', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName', 'data 1', data);

var replaced=data.toString().replace('\t', '');
if (isEmptyObject(replaced)) {
    res.status(400).send({error: errorMessage.emptyBody});
    return;
}

createLog('debug', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName', 'data 2', replaced);
Database.OrganizationPermissionsGroups.getOrganizationPermissionsGroupById(replaced).then(function (groupId) {
    if (groupId.length == 0) {
        res.status(404).end();
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(groups[0]);
    }
}).catch(function (e) {
    createLog('error', __dirname, __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3), null, 'getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName', e);
    res.status(500).send(e);
});

    }
```

Logs:

```
2|wscontro | [2017-08-23 17:38:40.326] - info: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/organization_permissions_groups OrganizationPermissionsGroupsController NA getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName inicio
2|wscontro | [2017-08-23 17:38:40.327] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/organization_permissions_groups OrganizationPermissionsGroupsController NA getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName data 1 "Monitor\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
2|wscontro | [2017-08-23 17:38:40.328] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/organization_permissions_groups OrganizationPermissionsGroupsController NA getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName data 2 "Monitor\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
2|wscontro | [2017-08-23 17:38:40.329] - info: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/organization_permissions_groups OrganizationPermissionsGroupsDatabase NA getOrganizationPermissionsGroupById inicio
2|wscontro | [2017-08-23 17:38:40.337] - error: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/organization_permissions_groups OrganizationPermissionsGroupsDatabase NA getOrganizationPermissionsGroupById { error: invalid input syntax for uuid: "Monitor                        "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [trim() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
 $scope.navigateToViews = function() {
    var btn = event.currentTarget;          
    var groupName = btn.parentNode.parentElement.innerText;
    groupName = groupName.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

after this line

```
if(groupName!=null){
```

you should replace \t with '' like that.

```
groupName=groupName.replace('\t', '');
```

Comment: It doens't work.. still appears /api/organization_permissions_groups/getPermissionGroupId/?permissionGroup=Monitor%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09 i nthe clientSide and 
2|wscontro | [2017-08-23 16:43:42.131] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/organization_permissions_groups OrganizationPermissionsGroupsController NA getOrganizationPermissionsGroupByName data "Monitor\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
 in server side (node)

Comment: does \t exist in console.log("groupName ",groupName); after doing change above?

Comment: No it just exists in my http.get url and in my backend req.query.permissionGroup understand?